# So, I can't flag as a Low Quality Post anymore, eh?

Tags: discussion, flagging

[An answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/are-dog-leg-braces-an-acceptable-alternative-to-prohibitively-expensive-knee-sur/5846#5846) I had to review had a lot of text that was unsubstantiated and inferred it referred to two articles.

One article link didn't go to anything, and the other one implied the user should search for the link.

My initial reaction was to flag for LQP and leave a comment that we needed some statements to be substantiated, but apparently that facility isn't here anymore.

So... what are the options for this?  Are we just down-voting and leaving a drive-by comment like I did (a.k.a. leaving it "as is"), or are we flagging as LQP, or are we creating a new "facts need to be backed up" sort of flag?

Comment: I can see the option for low quality.

Comment: "it is very low quality" *WAS NOT* there earlier today when I posted this.  It is there now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option is only available on posts scoring <=0.

Very Low Quality = irredeemable garbage; generally you should avoid using it for answers that are merely *incorrect*. Instead, down vote and leave a comment noting the inaccuracies or omissions.

Comment: Thanks.  The post scored 1 at the time I had it under review; my downvote moved it to 0, but I'm not sure if I checked flag before or after voting, or whether LQP option would have appeared after my downvote made it 0 during the review session.